# child on SCSS transition item causes the parent's border size to change in firefox

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

working on SCSS transition I made two classes trigger and box and while hovering on trigger box should start moving and rotating.

```
.trigger {
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: 20px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25% 25%;

  &:hover {
    .box {
      transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
    }
  }
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

the effect works fine on chrome
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2CnC.png

however Firefox scales the trigger borders
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OVW4.png

the jade code

```
.trigger
    .box
```

Comment: Note that questions should only be tagged with tags relevant to the problem. I've removed the Pug tag for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `position: relative` to `.trigger` and `position: absolute` to the box. I didn't have your html so I took a guess at what it might look like. this solution seems to work at least in codepen (I viewed in Chrome and Firefox and both are working). I had to modify your scss to css in this example in order to tinker with it in codepen and post here.

```css
.trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: 20px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% 25%;
}
.trigger:hover .box {
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```